# How to scroll long text in TextView indefinitely

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate my TextView indefinitely when text is too long. I found some solution but it is reseting after 2 seconds back to start of the text even if some text is still needed to scroll. I need animation infinite and it should scroll whole text and at the end start of the text will appear.
Same as those information boards on train stations.

This is my animation right now:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

There is repeat count but I dont want to repeat animation and reset to initial position but animate it all the time.

Comment: use ellipsize="marquee" instead of animation .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need an animation, a simple Marquee TextView would do:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Your Sample text here" />
```

Make sure you have the marquee mode set (in the `ellipsize` attribute as above) and the maximum lines set to 1 for it to work. You can choose to repeat it indefinitely, or a specific amount of times, by replacing the `marquee_forever` with an integer.

Comment: Lastly, for this to work you must call `textView.setSelected(true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stop repeat mode nad set view at the initial point then you can set count as -1.

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

You can set `repeatmode` as `Animation.REVERSE` if you need.

And need to do dynamically then can use following way.

```
   mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f);
   mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
   mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
   mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
   mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
   mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/rv_item_tv_address"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
       android:scrollHorizontally="true"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:text="address"
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:textSize="20sp"
      />
```